# The tilde construction of a finitely generated $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$-module.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be an affine scheme with structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{X}$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$-module, say $s_{1},...,s_{n}$ are the generators. We consider the ''tilde-construction" applied to $M$ to obtain an $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module $\widetilde{M}$. Notice that $\widetilde{M}(X) = M$ and thus is also finitely generated. As a consequence I came up with the following question.

**Question:** Is the sheaf $\widetilde{M}$ also in some sense finitely generated? For instance, do we have for every open $U\subset X$ that $s_{1}\rvert_{U},...,s_{n}\rvert_{U}$ generate $\widetilde{M}(U)$ as $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{X})$-module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion you are looking for is for a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of $O_X$ modules to be "finitely generated by global sections," meaning there is a collection $\{s_i\}\in\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})$ so that the images of the $s_i$ generate the stalk $\mathcal{F}_x$ as an $O_{X,x}$-module for every $x\in X$. Here's an exercise for you (it's not difficult, I promise): Let $\mathcal{F}=\widetilde{M}$ on Spec $A$. Show that any set of generators for $M$ as an $A$-module generate $\mathcal{F}$ as an $O_X$ module. Futhermore, if $M$ is finitely generated, so if $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: 1) This does not address the second part of the OP's bolded question. 2) The notion of a [sheaf of finite type](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01B5) may also be useful (this is a slight generalization of what you're talking about).

Comment: In the case of the given example we have $X=\text{Spec}(A)$, consequently if we pick $\mathfrak{p}\in \text{Spec}(A)$ we see that $\mathcal{F}_{\mathfrak{p}} = \widetilde{M}_{\mathfrak{p}}=M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X,\mathfrak{p}} = A_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Thus we indeed easily see that if $s_{1},...,s_{n}$ generate $M = \mathcal{F}(X)$ as $A$-module, then their images generate $\mathcal{F}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ as an $\mathcal{O}_{X,\mathfrak{p}}$-module for every $\mathfrak{p}\in \text{Spec}(A)$.

Comment: For the second part of the question I want to use the notion of a sheaf of finite type as mentioned by KReiser. These sections $s_{1},...,s_{n}$ induce an $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module homomorphism $u:\mathcal{O}_{X}^{(n)}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ defined by for each open $V\subset X$ and $(t_{1},...,t_{n})\in \mathcal{O}_{X}(V)^{n}$, $u_{V}(t_{1},...,t_{n}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}t_{i}s_{i}\rvert_{V}$. Now I want this map to be surjective, but I don't see why this is the case.